# Perform a simple multiplication with jquery after a slider value is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, nouislider

I need some advice (help) on the most efficient way to implement a form that incorporates a range slider to set a value (in this case annual mileage), then takes that value and multiplies it by a set constant (0.05) and plugs the result into a second form field with a unit of British Pounds (£) and an accuracy of 2 decimal places rounded as appropriate. I am using a slider called No UI Slider (http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) and have set up the basic elements here:

```
$("#sliderAnnualMileage").noUiSlider({
start: [ 0 ],
step: 1000,
range: {
'min': [ 0 ],
'max': [ 120000 ]
 },
connect: "lower",
serialization: {

lower: [

  $.Link({
    target: $("#mileage"),
    format: {
      thousand: ',',
      decimals: 0,
      postfix: ' miles'
     }
    })
  ]
 }
});
```

Here is a partially working JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/highlander/jMA98/1/
Any insight or experience you have would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set another `$.Link` to the second input box, with a formatting function:

```
lower: [
  // your one
  // then this:
  $.Link({
    target: $("#annualSavings"),
    method: function (val) {
        $(this).val("£" + (val * 0.05).toFixed(2));
    }
  })
]
```

This is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/jMA98/3/

Comment: Thank you! This is spot on.

Comment: One other small item here: I tried to use the "format" option of the .Link element to add a comma in the thousands place on the output, but when I do, I get a NaN error message. Do I need to format it within the function?

Comment: You need to read the API to see if you can use the `format` with the function method. My guess is that you can't and need to add the comma yourself in the function.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason your slider resets the value.

http://jsfiddle.net/jMA98/2/

```
$('#mileage').on('change',function(){
    console.log($(this).val().replace(' miles',''));
    $('#annualSavings').val($(this).val().replace(' miles','')*0.05);
});
```

Other than that this works.